# AWS S3 SelectObjectContent not returning results in AWS SDK v2 for Go

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, sdk

I'm having difficulty getting `SelectObjectContent` to return any details. The frustrating part is that the query works in the console.

My test object is a simple JSON file stored in a test bucket:

```
{
  "Name": "Kevin",
  "Role": "engineer",
  "Color": "blue"
}
```

and my query is equally simple:

```
SELECT * FROM s3object LIMIT 5
```

Below is the function I've assembled for a specific use case:

```
func S3SelectObjectContent(bucket, region, objectKey, expression string) (*s3.SelectObjectContentOutput, error) {
    client := s3.NewFromConfig(Config, func(o *s3.Options) {
        o.Region = region
    })

    input := &s3.SelectObjectContentInput{
        Bucket:         &bucket,
        Key:            &objectKey,
        Expression:     &expression,
        ExpressionType: types.ExpressionTypeSql,
        InputSerialization: &types.InputSerialization{
            JSON: &types.JSONInput{
                Type: types.JSONTypeDocument,
                // Type: types.JSONTypeLines
            },
            CompressionType: types.CompressionTypeGzip,
        },
        OutputSerialization: &types.OutputSerialization{
            JSON: &types.JSONOutput{
                RecordDelimiter: aws.String("\n"),
            },
        },
    }

    result, err := client.SelectObjectContent(context.TODO(), input)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return result, nil
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help and ideas.

I've tried adjusting the `bucket` and `objectKey` ... I get a "not found" if these are incorrect.

I've confirmed I have access to the bucket as I'm able to print the listing of objects using `ListObjectsV2`

I've confirmed the code is reading something, because if I point to a non-GZIP'd version of the file, it complains the file is not compressed.

My sandbox bucket is private and has a minimal bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Statement1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::kkevin-testbucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::kkevin-testbucket/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:PrincipalAccount": "123456789064"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

EDIT: I can confirm that this CLI command also works and generates correct output:

```
aws s3api select-object-content \
    --bucket kkevin-testbucket \
    --key testfile.json.gz \
    --expression "select * from s3object limit 5" \
    --expression-type 'SQL' \
    --input-serialization '{"JSON": {"Type": "Document"}, "CompressionType": "GZIP"}' \
    --output-serialization '{"JSON": {}}' "output.json" \
    --profile sandbox
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct. I added some print statements to your `S3SelectObjectContent` function as follows

```
stream := result.GetStream()
defer stream.Close()

for event := range stream.Events() {
    v, ok := event.(*types.SelectObjectContentEventStreamMemberRecords)
    if ok {
        value := string(v.Value.Payload)
        fmt.Print(value)
    }
}

if err := stream.Err(); err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
```

and I got the following output

```
{"Name":"Kevin","Role":"engineer","Color":"blue"}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I think I have been confused about how to extract the stream rules and this example helps!